# "Improving pain", is it desirable?

Tags: interpretation

I have read improving together with terms like pain multiple times, and never was confident this means the pain is reduced so its an improvement of pain in a sense of suffering.

Or it might mean the pain is improved in a sense of making it more intense.

What obvious would result in opposite meanings.

So which of the cases it is expected to be? Or is this in itself depending on context?

Comment: While I think most people will interpret it as lessening the suffering from pain, it may be better to say reducing pain or alleviating pain. Most instances of "improving pain" are similar to "improving [pain management](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=10513)" or "improving pain outcomes".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a tricky one. Going by bare definitions according to the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary, *improve* means

> [to (​cause something to) get ​better](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/improve)

while *pain* means

> [a ​feeling of ​physical ​suffering ​caused by ​injury or ​illness](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pain)

Taken literally, if you described the suffering *itself* getting better, rather than the feeling associated with it, that would mean the actual pain is getting *worse* because from the perspective of the pain, hurting you more is a good thing (I didn't foresee myself anthropomorphising pain today, but there you go).

However, most people would interpret "my pain has improved" as meaning that you're feeling *less* pain than you were, as very few people outside the realm of sociopaths would consider you feeling more pain as an improvement.

The bottom line is that it's fine to use this construction, but only because nobody is cruel enough to apply the literal meaning of the words. :P

Comment: Thats the point, I have a tendency to take things literal. And therefor when I read improving pain I understood it as the pain itself icnreased. But sometimes it made me ask "Do they really want to express that?" and soemtimes it simply made no sense. So the conclusion is, my understanding was right, but anyway that one simply isn't used in a literal way?

Comment: That's the answer I'd give you, at least. I don't see anyone use the term "improving pain" in the literal sense.

Comment: Reminds me of *Will you turn the air conditioner (a/c)  up?* Does this mean the person wants the air conditioner to work more so it will make the room colder, or does it mean, turn the air conditioner's thermostat up, so the a/c will come on less often and therefore make the room less cool. Native speakers have this conversation about *turn the a/c up* all the time. One would think we would have figured out what we mean by now.

Comment: I would interpretat *Is your pain improving/getting better?* to mean *Are you feeling/sensing **less** pain?*

Comment: @Wyatt That's the problem with English: so many different interpretations of the same sequence of words.

Comment: "Pain" is a bad thing (in most contexts), "improvement" is making something better, so an improvement of a bad thing would be less of it. There _are_ some people who _like_ pain in certain situations, but they're considered aberrations or at least a little bit odd.

Comment: @T.J.L. It depends on the perspective from which you're considering "improvement"; it doesn't always mean "make something better for the person experiencing it", which is why I pointed out that if you're looking at it from the pain's point of view, improving would be making the pain worse. ;)

Comment: @JohnClifford I don't think pain is entitled to a point of view. :)

Comment: @T.J.L. Well that's just paincist.

Comment: Similarly, if someone says "my pain has worsened", they surely mean they're feeling *more* pain, not *less*.

Comment: If you are buying an instrument of torture, improvement of pain would be ok. If not, you should avoid because it means that (make the pain better, a better pain) not a lesser pain.

Comment: If a person is *a pain in the neck*, and he's improved, what does that mean regarding his character or actions? Depends on perspective, I guess.